# Pictures not showing up on Dockerised PHP container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

#### Problem

I have Dockerised my PHP project, and for some reason the pictures from directory "icons" are not being displayed, but from "images" it's being shown. On console it shows up as 404 Not Found. I tried to move the picture from "icons" to "images" and then it shows up. Not really sure what could be the problem.

#### Working tree

```
.
 ┣ mysql_data
 ┃ ┗ database_dump.sql
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ icons
 ┃ ┃ ┗ icon.png
 ┃ ┣ images
 ┃ ┃ ┗ photo.png
 ┃ ┗ index.php
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┗ docker-compose.yml
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  php-env:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000:80

  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: amazon
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql_data/database_dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/database_dump.sql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Comment: How do you “call” the image in your html? Maybe it’s the relative/absolute path that’s the issue…

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov <img src="icons/icon.png"> that's how I'm defining the path in index.php , and the same goes for when I'm getting the photos from "images" folder

Comment: can you please run `docker exec -it php-en ls -lah /var/www/html/icons/*` ? (note: `php-env` can be a bit different, run `docker ps` beforehand)

Comment: Maybe you have a .dockerignore that somewhy blocks these files to get in the container.

Comment: @EvgenyKolyakov the command returns ```no matches found: /var/www/html/icons/*``` , but if I run ```docker exec -t -i <container-id> /bin/bash``` I can see the "icons" folder there with all the files. And I haven't made .dockerignore file in this project